# How to decorate the Scala Int class with a custom impicit to convert to binary String

Tags: scala, int, implicit

I want to use the following method:

```
 def toBinary(i : Int, digits: Int = 8) =
                String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')
```

and turn it into a implicit conversion in order to "decorate" the scala Int class, RichInt so to achieve the following :

```
3.toBinary     //> res1: String = 00000011
3.toBinary(8)  //> res1: String = 00000011
```

instead of the call `toBinary(3)`

**How can i achieve this ?**

**[EDIT]**
After looking to the link sugested i got the following which works

```
implicit class ToBinaryString(i :Int ) {
    def toBinary(digits: Int = 8) =
                String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')
  }

  3.toBinary(8)                                   //> res2: String = 00000011
```

I can't use it though without the default parameter, i would like to be able to write `3.toBinary`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: How can I create a function that allows me to use dot notation when calling it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621321/scala-how-can-i-create-a-function-that-allows-me-to-use-dot-notation-when-calli)

Comment: You should be able to use it with the default parameter `3.toBinary()`. If you want to skip the parenthesis you'll have to add another method `def toBinary = toBinary(8)` and remove the default parameter from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object A extends App {
  implicit class RichInt(i: Int) {
    def toBinary(digits: Int = 8): String =
      String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')
  }

  println(3.toBinary(6))
}
```

Prints:

```
000011
```

// EDIT
If you want to call 3.toBinary without parenthesis I guess you have to provide a method without parameters:

```
object A extends App {
  implicit class RichInt(i: Int) {
    def toBinary(digits: Int): String =
      String.format("%" + digits + "s", i.toBinaryString).replace(' ', '0')

    def toBinary: String = toBinary(8)
  }

  println(3.toBinary)
  println(3.toBinary(6))
}
```

This one works for me but I'm not Scala expert so there might be better way of doing this.

Comment: I worked out the same solution check my comment on the edit

Comment: Yeah. You must have edited your post couple seconds after my answer :)

Comment: DRY: `def toBinary = toBinary(8)`

Comment: Yeah. It's just an example but I should have done it right :)